# SQL Server 2008 SP2 - Object Explorer Hangs During Actions or While Expanding

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

I am running an SQL Server 2008 SP2 instance on my work desktop. Recently, after a power outage, I began having issues with the Object Explorer pane (from both local and remote connections). I can query against the databases fine using T-SQL, but if I attempt to initiate any actions using the Object Explorer (Import Data, Update Linked Server, run SQL Agent job), SSMS hangs and I am forced to close the application using Task Manager. Until I reboot the server instance, the Object Explorer will hang indefinitely upon connecting. When it hangs, there doesn't seem to be any unusual network or resource utilization and SSMS.exe does not show the typical "not responding" during a freeze.

The server only hosts data for my own projects, so it isn't anything truly business-critical. As such, downtime is not a real issue. I encounter this hang when accessing the server locally and remotely, so I don't think it's just my SSMS copy. I do have all of the databases backed up, so if necessary I can restore on a new instance (if the issue is corruption), but I wanted to check if anyone had encountered this.

There are three linked servers (2 Oracle, 1 Postgres).

Answer (score 0):

Try executing ssms.exe-log filename and see if you get any more info.

Comment: I do not believe the log displays anything insightful. The SQL Server Agent log states "[364] The Messenger service has not been started - NetSend notifications will not be sent." There are no warnings under SQL Server log.